# Normally on at NMOS transistor to control another circuit

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, switches, nmos, laser

I need to design a custom board with the ability to control interlock of the laser mechanism.
First of all, I have the product X with could get control from another circuit, this pin connect to internal interlock , I asked the product engineer how it works and this is answer:
"There is a 50 kΩ pulldown resistor to ground on that pin, and logic gate inputs are MΩ input impedance (negligible). Not sure what control voltage you’re using, so you’ll have to calculate the current accordingly by dividing by 50 kΩ"
You can use 3.3 V (or some other voltage between 2.2 and 6.0 V) from your own board and a transistor switch  to enable/disable the interlock.
This is from the product X spec (I need to connect to Pin2:
[image]

So I try to simulate the circuit and nothing works:
I want that the NMOS will be normally on-> means the interlock will be close(connect to GND)
[image]
The simulation result is interlock is always high which means it always works and it could be a disaster, what is wrong with my circuit? Am I missing something?
[image]

Comment: What are you trying to simulate? Why have a discreet inverter in the first place? In enhancement FET datasheets, think of \$V_{GS}th\$ as *off below*, *not* as *on above*.

Comment: (In the first schematic, M1 is parallel to the voltage source. In the second schematic, INTERLOCK is in one net with +3.3 V: What do you expect?)

Comment: I trying to simulate case that MCU send high or low, what I expected to happen when I send low , the FET is off and the voltage to interlock will be 3.3v, is like inverter. so the waves doesnt change in the Interlock pin, I try to simulate the black box

Comment: @greybeard Could you help me then, what did I misunderstand from the representative of the product who explained to me how to control the mechanism of the interlock? the first schematic refer that X is blackbox, but in the simulation I cant simulate black box so I designed what the field application engineer of the prodcut told me .

Comment: @greybeard Because V2 simulates the MCU, I'm afraid to directly connect an MCU pin to the interlock for safety reasons, especially after the product representative told me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142675/discussion-between-greybeard-and-knowledge).

Comment: @greybeard sent you there message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the interlock is a logic level input with an internal 50 kΩ pull-down resistor, you can directly connect the MCU to set it.

If you are afraid of safety or disallowed from galvanically connecting it, you can use an optical isolator like such (Only really makes sense, if `V1` is an isolated supply):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1NyUd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: where the Interlock pin should be connect?  to the emitter of the opto side?

Comment: Thanks, I looked a bit at optocouplers, I don't have time to switch them, for example ILD217 Do you know what this parameter is called? turn on / turn off time

Comment: The phototransistors in jelly bean optocouplers take a few µs to turn off. I think 3-4 µs is a good estimate :)